# DotNetOpenAuth Twitter Consume StartSignIn

Tags: dotnetopenauth, twitter-oauth

Trying to use the StartSignInWithTwitter method.  When the method is called soon after an exception is thrown.  This is using the latest version of DotNetOpenAuth.  Would it have anything to do with me developing and running with locally? (VS2010)  Is this how I should be doing authentication in the first place?  I do see some different ways in the Samples pack that is included with the source.

{"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}

My code looks like below:

```
    public void TwitAuthInit()
    {
        TwitterConsumer.StartSignInWithTwitter(false).Send();
    }

    public ActionResult TwitAuth()
    {
        if (TwitterConsumer.IsTwitterConsumerConfigured)
        {
            string screenName;
            int userId;
            if (TwitterConsumer.TryFinishSignInWithTwitter(out screenName, out userId))
            {

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(screenName, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Home", "Index");
            }

        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Can you add to your question whether the Twitter sample included with the distribution works for you?

Comment: I was NOT able to get it to work with the sample distribution either.  Same exact error.  Could it be dude to something on Twitters end?  I did register an application.  Do any of the URLs configured at Twitter have to match mine locally?  Could this be the issue as I am running through localhost with Visual Studio.

Comment: Most likely a registration problem with your Twitter consumer then.  Be sure to select App Type = Browser in your registration page.  The URL shouldn't matter, actually, in my experience.

Comment: Turns out I created another Twitter application.  I just made sure I filled in a Callback URL.  Everything is working now with success.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about "Is this how I should be doing authentication in the first place?":

You probably shouldn't be calling `SetAuthCookie(screenName, false)` with your `screenName`, since screen names (I believe) can be recycled.  You should instead log the user in using a unique ID, either one you create in your own user database or Twitter's, and then use the screen name only as an alias that is displayed to the user (and perhaps other users if this user were to post something for public viewing).  Otherwise, when Twitter recycles a username, that user will inherit all the data from the old user on your site -- not good.

Comment: Andrew - thanks for the comment, nice name too Andrew here as well. haha.  But yeah I do realize the screenName one.  I meant more so the proper code to call/accept response from Twitter. I have seen my way posted, also I have seen using the TokenManager.  What do you recommend?

Comment: There's always a TokenManager involved, so I'm not sure how "your way" vs. "using the TokenManager" differs.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to confirm that the 401 error is indeed solved by setting a non-empty callback URL on the twitter app config page.

From the Application Type block of the settings page:

> To restrict your application from using callbacks, leave this field
>   blank.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go into TwitterConsumer.cs and change the following URLs:

```
Request token URL   https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
Authorize URL   https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize
Access token URL    https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
```

As Twitter changed their URLs. I didn't get the memo and spent way too much time debugging this.